# PHP Regex | How to pull url from another line?

Tags: php, regex

I want to pull the link that contains index_5_av.m3u8

Im using regex, But i get the first link in the response:

```
/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
```

PHP:

```
$data = "#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=241000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=461000,RESOLUTION=416x234,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=861000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_3_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1361000,RESOLUTION=720x404,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_4_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2061000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3062000,RESOLUTION=1600x900,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_6_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4561000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_7_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d";

$re = '/sns([^(]+?)\s/';
preg_match($re, $data, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

*The content inside $data i get from a file on another webserver,

I edited, and added the content.

How can i pull only the index_5_av.m3u8 link?

Comment: You don't need `regex` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `regexp` for such a simple processing. Split the input data into lines and [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the lines that [contain the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) `index_5_av.m3u8`:

```
$data = <<< E
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=241000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=461000,RESOLUTION=416x234,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=861000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_3_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1361000,RESOLUTION=720x404,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_4_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2061000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3062000,RESOLUTION=1600x900,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_6_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4561000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_7_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
E;


$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$matches = array_filter(
    $lines,
    function($line) {
        return strpos($line, 'index_5_av.m3u8') !== false;
    }
);

print_r($matches);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [10] => https://staragvod1-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/sns/1364/1000055235_,16,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/index_5_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBwxF67ZwMhBu+3XVrS4UWCkUpXl1hGzzRVtOIGbC4tLT5KmX0zX6fB0Z5qlHfurL7v7kKGtVdEJA%3d%3d
)
```

Bonus, the keys (`10`) tell you the line numbers (start counting with `0`) of the matching lines (the 11<sup>th</sup> line in this case.)

---

A `regexp` solution:

```
// Initialize $data as in the previous block of code

$re = '#^http.*/index_5_av\.m3u8.*$#m';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($re, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It prints all matching lines. The `regexp` looks for lines that start with `http` and contain `/index_5_av.m3u8`. The [`m` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) tells [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match `^` and `$` against beginning and end of line, not against beginning and end of the input text (their default meaning when not multi-line.)

Comment: I added a `regexp` solution.